# Certain apps not launching in 22.04

Tags: desktop-apps

I'm having an issue where most apps will launch (Files, Terminal, Google Chrome), will launch and work fine. However, some, including Ubuntu Software and most 3rd party apps (except Chrome for some reason) will not start. When I try to launch, nothing happens, except for Ubuntu Software which at least provides evidence of [something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSZrN.png) on the top bar but ultimately goes away. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: New install or been running a while and now this error?

Comment: Run the commands in a terminal, `sudo apt update`, press ENTER. type your password when promoted. Then enter the command `sudo apt upgrade` ENTER. Then try again. If this does not work, try opening the apps by typing it's name in the terminal (note, the name to type may be different than the GUI name). Copy and paste the errors in the terminal into your question above.

Comment: You'll have to look in logs for clues (errors/warnings); though it's much easier in (*in my opinion*) to just open terminal & start the apps from there (*as already suggested!*) as the messages appear on the terminal screen (*saving you from searching logs*).  Common reasons maybe if you use GUI apps using `sudo` privileges, you can change permissions away from your default user for example (*permission denied type messages will be seen*) but you gave few specific details (what apps, change changes were made, how last used etc)

Comment: Looks like I didn't have snap installed for some reason! Thanks for the help guys